# how to use ORDER BY and aggregating results together in cypher query

Tags: neo4j

I have following graph created in neo4j. Here user1 has exchanged messages with user2 and user3

```
(user1)-[:EMAIL_SENT]->(Email)-[:EMAIL_TO]->(user2)
(user1)<-[:EMAIL_TO]-(Email)<-[:EMAIL_SENT]-(user2)
(user1)-[:EMAIL_SENT]->(Email)-[:EMAIL_TO]->(user3)
(user1)<-[:REPLY_TO]-(Email)<-[:REPLY_SENT]-(user3)
(user1)-[:REPLY_SENT]->(Email)-[:REPLY_TO]->(user3)
```

I would like to retrieve facebook style results for user1 i.e show latest message per participator(either sent or receive). Query below shows all the message sent and receive by user1 and to which participant, but I want to aggregate results per participant.

```
MATCH (U:User {username:'user1'})
    -[L:EMAIL_SENT|EMAIL_TO]-(E:email)-[R:EMAIL_SENT|EMAIL_TO]-
  (P:User) 
  WHERE type(L)<>type(R)
RETURN E.text as text, 
   E.subject as subject, 
   id(E) as message_id, 
   U.username as user, 
   P.username as participator, 
   (CASE type(L) WHEN 'EMAIL_SENT' THEN 'out' ELSE 'in' END) as direction
```

If I try something like this

```
MATCH (U:User {username:'user1'})
    -[L:EMAIL_SENT|EMAIL_TO]-(E:email)-[R:EMAIL_SENT|EMAIL_TO]-
  (P:User) 
  WHERE type(L)<>type(R)
RETURN E.text as text, 
   E.subject as subject, 
   id(E) as message_id, 
   U.username as user, 
   P.username as participator, 
   (CASE type(L) WHEN 'EMAIL_SENT' THEN 'out' ELSE 'in' END) as direction ORDER BY E.timestamp DESC,collect (E.text)
```

I get the error - "Cannot use aggregation in ORDER BY if there are no aggregate expressions in the preceding RETURN (line 5, column 1 (offset: 187)) "RETURN E.text as text,"

Also, I'm not sure how to group all the email by the participants after sorting by time stamp before using collect to retrieve all emails to specific participants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) When ordering you can not use the collect as property for which you need to arrange.

2) Try something like this:

```
// All interaction between the user `user1` and his partner
MATCH (U:User {username:'user1'})
        -[L:EMAIL_SENT|EMAIL_TO|REPLY_TO|REPLY_SENT]-
      (E:Email)
        -[R:EMAIL_SENT|EMAIL_TO|REPLY_TO|REPLY_SENT]-
      (P:User) 
      WHERE type(L)<>type(R)

  // Sorted by time and get the type of interaction (the direction of)
  WITH U, P, E, type(L) as D ORDER BY E.timestamp DESC

  // Get collect of interactions (email and direction) by partner
  WITH U, P, head( collect( {email: E, direction: D} ) ) as lastInteraction

// Return last interaction between user and his partner
RETURN U as User,
       P as Partner,
       lastInteraction['email']['subject'] as subject,
       lastInteraction['email']['text'] as text,
       lastInteraction['direction'] as direction
  ORDER BY lastInteraction['email']['timestamp'] DESC
```

Comment: Is it not possible to return properties for email such as text (email.text)? Like U.username as User

Comment: It shows direction as null now. In the previous query it was showing direction as REPLY_TO or REPLY_SENT or EMAIL_SENT or EMAIL_TO

Comment: Hey @stdob-- can you drop me an email at michael at neo4j.com ?

Comment: @MichaelHunger Yes, I did.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH (U:User {username:'user1'})-[L:EMAIL_SENT|EMAIL_TO]-(E:email)--(P:User)
WITH U, L, E, P
ORDER BY E.timestamp DESC
RETURN E.text as text, 
   E.subject as subject, 
   id(E) as message_id, 
   U.username as user, 
   P.username as participator, 
   (CASE type(L) WHEN 'EMAIL_SENT' THEN 'out' ELSE 'in' END) as direction;
```

It orders the emails by descending timestamp *before* the `RETURN` clause. It also simplifies the original `MATCH/WHERE` clauses.